# Why this graphite graph is dipping at the end?

Tags: graphite

This - [thisLink](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17137368/foo.png) is a sumSeries graph using the function as sumSeries(stats.counts.application.foo).

In the image, you can see the dip at the end. This is a false dip, there is always a dip at the end. To elaborate, if the current time is 10 AM, you see a dip in the graph at 10 AM. However, if you look at the graph at say 10:10 AM, the dip at 10AM is no longer present, but there is a dip at 10:10 AM. How can we fix this? We use `statsite` for populating this data, both `statsite` as well as graphite interval are set to 1 minute.

Comment: A wild guess that is probably something's going on with one of your series. Could you be more specific, i.e. show more code, how the series are formed, how exactly do you call `sumSeries`, etc?

Comment: This is counter data. Logstash is the transport agent and statsite is the one which sends it to graphite. This is the function - sumSeries(stats.counts.application.*.foo.*.MethodCall_increment). Let me know if I can give more info.

Comment: Could you dump these series as tables of numbers and then see which one of them is missing the data or has zeroes in the end?

Comment: I am not sure how would that help because if that was the problem why would the graph correct itself after sometime?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're using live data - eventually these data got appended to the file, so you get these missing rows and graph appears to correct itself.

Comment: Aha, good tip, let me try that out.